# Can I get around using "pip install --cert"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, ssl, certificate

Trying to figure out if there is a way that I can avoid using the --cert flag to pip when I am installing packages at work.  There is some issue with the proxy that only allows me to download the packages I need when I provide that flag, despite adding the `mycert.crt` file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and running `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

An example of the messages I'm seeing is:

```
$ pip install "virtualenv>=1.10.1"
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv>=1.10.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ when looking for download links for virtualenv>=1.10.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for virtualenv>=1.10.1
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ when looking for download links for virtualenv>=1.10.1
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv>=1.10.1
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv>=1.10.1
Storing complete log in /tmp/tmpwW5qXD
```

This can be solved with instead using:

```
pip install --cert=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert.crt
```

However, I would prefer to not have to do so (as I'm sure other applications bump into this issue).

I am running Linux Mint 15 (though I previously had very similar issues on Ubuntu 12.04), pip version 1.4.1.

Comment: This could be a potential duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377045/pip-cert-failed-but-curl-works .. I'm not sure what the policy is for aggregating etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set that through the pip configuration file, which is in `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` or `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` on Windows:

```
[global]
cert = /usr/local/share/ca-certificate/mycert.crt
```

This file lets you set basically all the flags that are used by pip. Full documentation is at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#configuration

Comment: I think your comment on my original post leads to the real answer, which is that pip does not use the system certs.  This is a good solution, though it runs into issues when I'm switching between the work and home environments (over VPN).  More an issue with the cert than the solution though.

Comment: Thanks @IanLee for that hint. Here's the supporting docs:

"Starting with v1.3, pip provides SSL certificate verification over HTTP, to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks against PyPI downloads. This does not use the system certificate store but instead uses a bundled CA certificate store. The default bundled CA certificate store certificate store may be overridden by using --cert option or by using PIP_CERT, REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE, or CURL_CA_BUNDLE environment variables."

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/?highlight=SSL%20Certificate%20Verification#ssl-certificate-verification

Answer (score 10):

For me, non of the config-file workarounds worked. I'm using **pip 1.5.4** on **Ubuntu 14.04**

What eventually worked for me is installing the certificate on the system first (for me on ubuntu this would be)

```
sudo cp ~/my_cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

The previous automatically updates the bundle file (checking at the bottom of `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` you should now see the same certificate as in `my_cert.crt`)

Now use that path in `PIP_CERT`. And add it to my `.bashrc`:

```
echo export PIP_CERT=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt >> ~/.bashrc
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I already posted this answer in SO (same answer as in the 'eventually duplicated link above', but at the beginning I didn't find the other (eventually duplicated answer)... so if someone like me gets here first, then this might help.

Maybe I'm breaking some kind of rules to post the same answer twice, one in SO and the other one in superuser. If so, sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me without needing to know where the config file lives:

```
python -m pip config set global.cert C:\\Path\\cert.crt
```

I believe you need pip version 10+, which you can find with:

```
 python -m pip --version
```

The output of the config set command then outputs the name of the config file for your convenience

Comment: Works for Windows to create a pip.ini file

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching environments and need both, the original `pip` certificates and your company certificates, you can bundle them together<sup>1</sup>:

```
cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert.crt $(python3 -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())") > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert-pip-bundle.crt
```

And set `pip` to use this bundle globally:

```
python3 -m pip config set global.cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert-pip-bundle.crt
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `python3 -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"` returns the path to the certificate bundle that is used by `pip` by default, which is not the system certificate store ([source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#ssl-certificate-verification)):

> Starting with v1.3, pip provides SSL certificate verification over HTTP, to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks against PyPI downloads. This does not use the system certificate store but instead uses a bundled CA certificate store. The default bundled CA certificate store certificate store may be overridden by using `--cert` option or by using `PIP_CERT`, `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`, or `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving here as a note to myself and hopefully to anyone who is using linux.

These are the directories on Linux that pip searches for a conf file in that order:

```
/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf
/etc/pip.conf
$HOME/.pip/pip.conf
$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
$VIRTUALENV/pip.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today and none of the work-arounds worked.  I found this post https://community.cisco.com/t5/cloud-security/umbrella-breaks-files-pythonhosted-org/td-p/3688704

and it mentioned that in troubleshooting they changed their DNS to google (8.8.8.8) and the problem went away.  I just tried that and it worked!  This is a situation where the content filtering product (CISCO Umbrella) needed updating

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind Zscaler here is what worked for me.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt` should include all the libraries you are planning load
e.g.:

- `fastapi`
- `uvicorn`
- `typing`